# Como fazer append de um componente JSX dentro de um item a partir de .map()

Tags: javascript, react, revisão-de-código

Tenho esta estrutura de linhas:

[image: Resultado da renderização do componente]

E minha ideia é que, ao clicar em cada linha, seja renderizado um componente JSX de acordo com o item que foi clicado. Consegui com o seguinte código, mas sinto que não é o mais correto a se fazer.

```
{itens.map(v => (
    <>
        <div className="tickets-row py-3" onClick={handleDataTicket} idx={v}>
            <div className="text-center">{v}</div>
            <div>Item 1</div>
            <div>Item 2</div>
            <div>{moment().format('DD/MM')}</div>
            <div>Problema</div>
            <div> <BiDownArrow /> </div>
        </div>
        
        {dataTicket[v] &&
            <Teste />
        }
    </>
))}
```

E a função que é disparada ao clicar na `div` é esta:

```
function handleDataTicket({target}){
    const v = target.parentNode.attributes.idx && target.parentNode.attributes.idx.value
    v && setDataTicket({[v]: !dataTicket[v]})
}
```

Funciona e posso passar os parâmetros na hora apenas de renderizar o `<Teste />` como em: `<Teste {...v} />`, mas seria essa a forma mais correta de fazer isso?

Gostaria de ideias para melhorar esse código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu diria que uma alternativa mais interessante é extrair a parte do código que corresponde ao **item da lista** para seu próprio componente.

Assim, ao invés de um único componente, responsável pela lista e pelos seus itens; você terá dois componentes – um para a lista e outro para os itens da lista.

A vantagem disso é que cada item da lista pode encapsular o seu estado e, portanto, resolver o problema em questão de forma um pouco mais “declarativa”. Veja um exemplo simples:

```
function List({ items }) {
  return items.map((v) => <ListItem key={v.id} data={v} />);
}

function ListItem({ data }) {
  const [isDataTicketVisible, setIsDataTicketVisible] = useState(false);

  function handleDataTicket() {
    setIsDataTicketVisible((prev) => !prev);
  }

  return (
    <div onClick={handleDataTicket}>
      <span>{data.name}</span>
      {isDataTicketVisible && <span>Ticket de {data.id} visível.</span>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Realmente, assim ficou muito mais fácil de controlar o componente, até porque provavelmente já iria precisar fazer esse controle por cada vez que abrir fazer uma chamada a uma api para buscar os dados referentes à aquele item. Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda :D