# Manipulação de state em um array

Tags: javascript, array, react

Tenho um `map((value: any, index: number))` que renderizo as informações vindas da API.

Dentro deste map crio os componentes, sendo um card para cada um. Gostaria que quando o usuário clicasse para expandir o card, expandisse somente o item e não todo os componentes.

O meu state está no topo do FC, sendo `const [show, setShow] = useState<boolean>(false);`

Quando faço o setShow, todos os componentes renderizados são abertos, qual a maneira de passar o `index` para o setShow ?

Comment: Veja se [esta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/523099/69296) ajuda.

Answer (score -2):

não sei se entendi muito bem a sua questão mas vou tentar responder aqui.

Como o seu state show tem um valor boleano acredito que você não vai conseguir colocar o index dentro dele. Você pode fazer um novo state para guardar só o index ou fazer um state com um obj que carregue essas duas informações. Mas nos dois casos seria melhor você salvar algum Id ao inves do index porque ele pode acabar fariando dependendo da API. Você pode criar uma função onClick que crie um objeto e set ele:

handleClick(event.target) {
const clickedCard = {
show: true,
id: event.target.id, *
};
setShow(clickedCard);
};

*tenta dar um console.log no event.target para você ver ao certo como chamar esse Id.

Era mais ou menos isso que você tava buscando?

Não sei se você quer exibir esse card na mesma rota ou em outra pagina. Mas se for em outra página você pode passar a info do id pelo history e nesse novo componente usar o id para fazer uma nova requisição.

Espero ter ajudado se quiser compartilhar um pouco mais do seu codigo pode ser que eu consiga ser mais acertiva.